# How to change change value of variable every time when I click on button

Tags: javascript, variables, numbers

I have two variables and I need to add number on value that is already inside variable every time when I click on button.

This is my code:

```
var x = e.pageX;
var y = e.pageY;
```

I have x an y variable and I need to add on x 30 and on y 22 every time when I click on button.But right now when I click on button I add this number just once and when I click again nothing happened.

```
var xLeft = x + 30;
var yTop = y + 22;
```

Comment: Take a look at examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check following example

```js
var x = 10
var y = 20
var xLeft=0
var yTop=0

function clickFunction() {
   xLeft +=  x + 30
   yTop +=  y + 22
   
   console.log("xLeft :" + xLeft)
   console.log("yTop :" + yTop)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="clickFunction()">Click Me!</button>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<button id="btn" onclick="myfunc()"></button>
```

js:

```
    function myfunc() {
      a += 2
    }
```